# how to make previous values to set in NHRangeSlider?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I had used NHRangeSlider for setting price range in my application placed in table view in which after setting the min and max ranges when i move to another view controller i was getting error and the last set values and normal values has been set in the slider how to clear this error ?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.section == 0{
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "sliderCell", for: indexPath) as! SliderCell
            tableView.isHidden = false
            activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
            let sliderView = NHRangeSliderView(frame: CGRect(x: 16, y: 28, width: self.view.bounds.width - 32, height: 80))
            sliderView.sizeToFit()
            cell.contentView.addSubview(sliderView)
            return cell
        }
        else{
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "brandCell", for: indexPath) as! BrandCell
            if selected == true{
            let value = values.count
            if (value == 1) {
                cell.brandsLabel.text = values[indexPath.row]
            }
            else if (value == 0) {
                let string = "no brand selected"
                cell.brandsLabel.text = string
            }
            else {
                let total = " &"+" \(value-1) more"
                print(total)
                cell.brandsLabel.text = "\(values[0])" + total
            }
            }
            return cell
        }
    }
```

[image is as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwz1I.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are always adding a new instance of `NHRangeSliderView` to your cell:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "sliderCell", for: indexPath) as! SliderCell
tableView.isHidden = false
activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
let sliderView = NHRangeSliderView(frame: CGRect(x: 16, y: 28, width: self.view.bounds.width - 32, height: 80))
sliderView.sizeToFit()
cell.contentView.addSubview(sliderView)
return cell
```

Assuming that you are reloading the cell/tableview somewhere else you will find that this piece of code is always adding a brand new slider view to the content view of your cell, since it is reusing the cell that already has an instance of the `NHRangeSliderView` in it.

In this situation I would recommend creating a custom table view cell that already has the slider view attached this way you will have a slightly simpler `cellForRow(atIndexPath:)` method, but also you won't need to worry about continually adding the view.

Comment: when we scroll the tableview, slider value was changed and its added once again to the content view what we do for this.?